# When clicking on QPushButton PyQT5 QTableView shows and immediately dissapear after that

Tags: pyqt

```
class FunituresModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FunituresModel, self).__init__()
        self.furnitures = []

    def set_furnitures(self, furnitures):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.furnitures = furnitures
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.furnitures)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not self.hasIndex(index.row(), index.column()) or role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        furniture = self.furnitures[index.row()]
        if index.column() == 0:
            return furniture.get_name()
        elif index.column() == 1:
            return furniture.get_quality()
        elif index.column() == 2:
            return furniture.get_room_number()

        return QVariant()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            if not self.is_valid_row_index(section):
                return QVariant()
            else:
                return section + 1
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            if not self.is_valid_column_index(section):
                return QVariant()
            else:
                if section == 0:
                    return "Room Number"
                elif section == 1:
                    return "Name"
                elif section == 2:
                    return "Quality"
        return QVariant()

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if self.is_valid_row_index(row) and self.is_valid_column_index(column):
            return self.createIndex(row, column)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def is_valid_row_index(self, row_index):
        return 0 <= row_index and row_index < self.rowCount()

    def is_valid_column_index(self, column_index):
        return 0 <= column_index and column_index < self.columnCount()

    def parent(self, child):
        return QModelIndex()



def show_furniture_table(furnitures):
    table = QTableView()
    table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
    model = FunituresModel()
    model.set_furnitures(furnitures)
    table.setModel(model)
    table.show()
```

It is really strange because when use the code from show_furniture_table in main function it works. But when in my form choose from combobox furniture and click, it shows and immediately. And also when it shows for sometime, it seems that there is no info in qtableview. Any help wouble great appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of `table` is tied to the `show_furniture_table` function. When this function returns, `table` falls out of scope and is deleted by Python's garbage collection mechanism. You need to return a reference to `table` from `show_furniture_table` if you want it to exist beyond the scope of the function.